# Expressionengine if statement destroying code

Tags: if-statement, expressionengine

I have finally (I think) managed to implement a second language using the multi language alternative wiki in ExpressionEngine.

The problem I’m having is that when i try and add the following if statement (or others)

```
{if country_code == “fr”} {/if}
```

around my otherwise fine navee navigation tag, the whole page becomes destroyed.
Upon viewing source, adding the if statement removes LOTS of code before and after it.

It is removing closing  tags from before and after the statement, effectively sending the page all over the place.

Does anyone know why this may be the case?

EDIT: Here is the full code:

```
<div id="top_links">

            <ul id="top_links_list">

                <li>t: +33 (0)467 45 90 00</li>
                <li>e: <a href="mailto:#>Email</a></li>



                {if segment_1 == "hotel" OR segment_1 == "contact"}
                    <li class="hotel_reserve">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">{if country_code == "fr"}Réservez votre séjour{/if}{if country_code == "en"}Reserve your stay{/if}</a>
                    </li>
                {/if}

                {if segment_1 == "restaurants" AND segment_2 !="reservations" AND segment_2 !="merci"}
                    <li class="restaurants_reserve">
                        <a href="{path="restaurants/reservations"}">{if country_code == "fr"}Réservez votre table{/if}{if country_code == "en"}Reserve your table{/if}</a>
                    </li>
                {/if}

                {if segment_1 == "golf" AND segment_2 !="reservations" AND segment_2 !="merci"}
                    <li class="golf_reserve">
                        <a href="{path="golf/reservations"}">{if country_code == "fr"}Réservez votre départ{/if}{if country_code == "en"}Reserve your tee-time{/if}</a>
                    </li>
                {/if}

                {if segment_1 == "evenements" AND segment_2 !="reservations" AND segment_2 !="merci"}
                    <li class="evenements_reserve">
                        <a href="{path="evenements/reservations"}">{if country_code == "fr"}Demandez un devis{/if}{if country_code == "en"}Get a quote{/if}</a>
                    </li>
                {/if}

                {if segment_1 == "competitions" AND segment_2 == "view"}
                    <li class="competitions_retour">
                        <a href="{path="competitions"}">{if country_code == "fr"}Retour au page compétitions{/if}{if country_code == "en"}Return to competitions page{/if}</a>
                    </li>
                {/if}

                {if segment_1 == "competitions" AND segment_2 == "merci"}
                    <li class="competitions_retour">
                        <a href="{path="{segment_1}"}">Retour au page {segment_1}</a>
                    </li>
                {/if}

                {if segment_1 == "golf" AND segment_2 == "merci"}
                    <li class="competitions_retour">
                        <a href="{path="{segment_1}"}">Retour au page {segment_1}</a>
                    </li>
                {/if}

                {if segment_1 == "restaurants" AND segment_2 == "merci"}
                    <li class="restaurants_reserve">
                        <a href="{path="{segment_1}"}">Retour au page {segment_1}</a>
                    </li>
                {/if}

                {if segment_1 == "evenements" AND segment_2 == "merci"}
                    <li class="evenements_reserve">
                        <a href="{path="{segment_1}"}">Retour au page {segment_1}</a>
                    </li>
                {/if}

                {if segment_1 == "merci"}
                    <li class="evenements_reserve">
                        <a href="{path="contact"}">Retour au page contact</a>
                    </li>
                {/if}

                {if segment_1 == "events" AND segment_2 == "view"}
                    <li class="evenements_reserve">
                        <a href="{path="events"}">Retour au page Events</a>
                    </li>
                {/if}

            </ul>


        </div> <!-- end top links -->   

            {if country_code == "fr"}
        {exp:navee:nav nav_title="main_nav" id="nav" parent_selected_class="parent_selected" selected_class_on_parents="true"}
             {/if}

    </div> <!-- end top right area -->

    <div class="clear"></div>

    </div> <!-- END TOP AREA -->
```

Thanks.

Comment: I answered. Please mark my answer.

Comment: The OP cannot accept answers yet.

Comment: Thanks, but the code change doesn't help, I've added the whole code in the post, perhaps there's another error?

Comment: Sorry I had removed the if tag on my site so that it works ok but have now edited it back into the post. Around the navee tag

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would use probably [Switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) which is far better then tons of if conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Your source code seems to have fancy quotes:

```
{if country_code == “fr”} {/if}
{if country_code == "fr"} {/if}
```

See the difference? Try the second line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you adhere to the directory listing rules and have created all directories and matching folders and rules, [referenced](http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Multi_language_site_alternative).

Change your code to this:

```
<h2 class="title">{if country_code= "fr"} Bonjour !{/if}</h2>
```

Note the quote marks are "" and not “” and no double ==

Comment: Thanks but think the curlys was me putting it into SO without the code  button